# Convergence measure in the $\infty$ exercise

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

[image]

**1**-How can $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu\{x\in D:|f_n(x)-f(x)>0|\}=1$ if there is an $N$ so that for $n\geqslant N$,$\epsilon>0$, $|\frac{1}{n}-0|<\epsilon$? I mean  $lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$ which is not higher than 0 which implies that $\mu\{x\in D:|f_n(x)-f(x)>0|\}=\mu\{x\in D:|0>0|\}=0$. How can $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu\{x\in D:|f_n(x)-f(x)>0|\}=1$?

**2**- What is the intuition behind this example? How can a function converge but not converge in measure?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $f_n$, the measure of the set where the function is positive is 1 since for any $x \in [0,1]$, the function value $f_n(x) > 0$. Therefore since $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$,
$$ \mu(\{x \in D: |f_n(x) - f(x)| > 0\}) = 1 \; \textbf{for every $n$} $$
and therefore the limit of this **sequence of measures as $n \to \infty$** is 1 as well, even though there is pointwise convergence at each $x$ to 0.

So maybe the best way to think about this is that the sequence of measures is different than the sequence of numbers corresponding to the function values at a fixed $x$. For each $x \in D$, yes it is true that $f_n(x) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ But the sequence of measures where these functions are positive is always 1.